# Sending of a steganographic message from client to server and vice versa

Tags: file-transfer, client-server, image-file

I have an image steganography module in my project. It works perfectly fine on a client side implementation.

What I want to do is, after the message is embedded in the image, to send the image to a server. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are various way. You can FTP that to a server, send it as a mail attachment, open a socket and send it to the server N bytes at a time...

You should be a bit more clear about your set-up.